# CloudSim: Adding components

Tags: components, cloudsim

All!

Now, I'm designing a cloud storage simulation using CloudSim, but wondering that CloudSim provides a function to write data on a physical disk. If not, where do I add the component?

Answer (score 1):

CloudSim will only simulate a physical storage device. Instead of interacting directly with it, you should describe the physical disk's behavior by implementing the [Storage interface](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Storage.java).